# XSLT Remove node but keep contents

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to remove a node but inject the content in the ancestors node. This is the xml :

```
    <w lemma="comment2" type="adv." ana="comment">comment</w>
<name ref="roland"><w lemma="roland" type="nom propre" ana="roland">roland</w></name>
<w lemma="faire" type="vindps3" ana="fyt"><choice><orig>fyt</orig><reg>fist</reg></choice></w>
<name ref="yvon de montauban"><w lemma="yvon" type="nom propre" ana="yvon">yvon</w>
<w lemma="de" type="prép" ana="de">de</w>
```

My wish is to delete completedly `<reg>` and it's content, to delete the tag `<choice>` and delete the tag `<orig>` BUT put it's content into the `<w>` tag. Can someone please help me ?

The xslt is for now like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="div">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="s">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="pb">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@ed='bnf'">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="w">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="descendant::orig">
                <xsl:element name="w">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="descendant::reg">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="w">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="choice"/>
    <xsl:template match="orig">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="reg"/> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you for your help :)
Micha

Comment: My wish is to delete completedly reg-tag and it's content, to delete the choice-tag and delete the orig-tag BUT put it's content into the w-tag.

Comment: Your XML isn't well-formed. You've not provided the expected output. Please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a **well-formed** XML input:

```
<root>
  <w lemma="comment2" type="adv." ana="comment">comment</w>
  <name ref="roland">
    <w lemma="roland" type="nom propre" ana="roland">roland</w>
  </name>
  <w lemma="faire" type="vindps3" ana="fyt">
    <choice>
      <orig>fyt</orig>
      <reg>fist</reg>
    </choice>
  </w>
  <name ref="yvon de montauban">
    <w lemma="yvon" type="nom propre" ana="yvon">yvon</w>
    <w lemma="de" type="prép" ana="de">de</w>
  </name>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="choice|orig">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reg"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <w lemma="comment2" type="adv." ana="comment">comment</w>
   <name ref="roland">
      <w lemma="roland" type="nom propre" ana="roland">roland</w>
   </name>
   <w lemma="faire" type="vindps3" ana="fyt">fyt</w>
   <name ref="yvon de montauban">
      <w lemma="yvon" type="nom propre" ana="yvon">yvon</w>
      <w lemma="de" type="pr√©p" ana="de">de</w>
   </name>
</root>
```

Note:

1. The `choice` wrapper has been removed;
2. The contents of `orig` have become the contents of the ancestor `w`
   node;
3. The entire `reg` node has been suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer, but it can't be formatted in a comment field.

Your XSLT code could be improved so much! For example instead of

```
<xsl:template match="w">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="descendant::orig">
                <xsl:element name="w">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
```

you could write

```
<xsl:template match="w[.//orig]">
  <w>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </w>
</xsl:template>
```